# Search for the first positive value cell after the highest negative value in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

I have a range of cells with cash flow values some are positive and some are negative within different ranges.

I am trying to find the cell that contains the highest negative value and search for the next positive value after it.

Here is an example of the rage of cells:
[image]

I am trying to get the value of the $627,744

Here is what I have started thinking of:
=min(a1:f1)

but I am not sure if it is possible to set a logic to extract the next positive value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this formula

```
=INDEX(A1:F1,
    MATCH(1,--(INDEX(A1:F1,MATCH(MIN(A1:F1),A1:F1,0)):F1>0),0)
    MATCH(MIN(A1:F1),A1:F1,0)-1
 )
```

[image]

- This part

  `INDEX(A1:F1,MATCH(MIN(A1:F1),A1:F1,0)):F1`

  builds a variable range starting from the min-value (the `INDEX`-part) to the last value of the list (`F1` in this case).
- This variable list is compared to `0`.
- The `--()`-part converts the `TRUE/FALSE`-list to a `1/0`-list.
- The surrounding `MATCH` finds the position of the first `1` (value greater zero).
- Then the position of the smallest value is added

  `MATCH(MIN(A1:F1),A1:F1,0)`
- Finally the overlapping range-part needs to be subtracted `-1`.

I hope this explanation is somewhat helpful. For further information i would refer to the formula evaluation-tool.

Comment: Could you please explain the function to understand how it works